# Bash script that runs a command with arguments and redirects

Tags: bash

So I'm trying to execute a command in a bash script multiple times with different but same number of arguments while redirecting the output to a text file.  For example ...

```
./test arg1 arg2 arg3 >> output.txt
```

This works if I do it at the command line.  In a script where I have...

```
command ./test 10 5 option1 >> output.txt


command ./test 5 10 option2 >> output.txt
```

And run the script, I get `command not found`.  If I remove the redirect to ouput.txt, the script then works / prints to the terminal window

I tried searching online but I could not find examples where arguments were used which then redirected

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Why do you have `command ./test` in the script and `./test` otherwise? Please, post the *actual* lines that you tried.

Comment: I thought you needed command as a prefix for a bash script.  I got it from some website.  As for the actual text, it's a class project I'm testing.  The actual program / arguments won't matter

Comment: You need `command` only if the command is a builtin you want to override (like using a different `echo` or `kill`). Well, how can you decide whether the actual program or arguments matter, when clearly you have something that should work (with or without `command`), and it doesn't? Maybe one of your script's arguments is a special character. Maybe you ran the script in a different directory. Leave the decision making to us.

Comment: Ok I made the change.  It's two ints and a string

Comment: The rest of the details as well? The script you used, how you ran the script, whether you were in the same directory when you ran the script and the commands?

Comment: SImple solution make the first redirect a direct write `>` and not an append `>>`. your simply trying to write into a file which dooes not exist. Or add the line `touch output.txt`above all others. There is a nice little tool which can really help you debugging scripts, its called `shellcheck`simply google for it.

Comment: Can  you edit your question so that you can add an example script that we can test.  Any script I write works and always redirect with the append (`>>`) redirection.  I can't identify directly with what would actual fail.  I can't tell you what you're doing wrong when every test I try works.  I can, by the way, give a formatted example in an answer of an example that works.

Comment: Here the [link](http://www.shellcheck.net/) for shellcheck, found it in my bookmarks.

Comment: Can you use a `./test arg1 arg2 arg3 | tee -a output.txt` to append all the output from your script?

Comment: I figured this out - 1) I did need to change the first line like Videonauth suggested.  2) I was writing the script in Windows and using it Unix.  Looks like there was an issue with line endings.  Switching the mode in Sublime Text did the trick.  Sorry, I'm not as familiar with Linux and forgot that creating text files in Windows can cause some havoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with writing the script in Windows in Sublime Text and then transferring it to a Linux server.  Switching the mode in Sublime Text made the difference

Videonauth also pointed out that I should have just one redirect symbol ">" since for the first line since it is a new file